# Python facial recognition script halting unexpectedly

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition, dlib

This isn't actually my script, but after a lot of back and forth with the creator, he's as stumped as I am, so I'm posting on his behalf since he can't replicate the issue and debug it.

The script is called faceripper9000 (based on [GetFaces](https://github.com/Tyrannosaurus1234/GetFaces)), and it's supposed to take a directory full of MP4s, and a photo of a target person, then output every frame where they appear in the clips.

You can see the script [here](https://github.com/MotorCityCobra/face_ripper_9000), but I'll add it to the bottom of this post too.

Dependancies are numpy, opencv, dlib and face_recognition, all of which appear to be installed correctly, but when the rest of us run the script we're getting this message:

```
File "demo.py", line 161, in
os.rename(i, too_small + "/too small-" + str(counter) + random_string(15) + ".jpg")
NameError: name 'random_string' is not defined
```

We can get around that by replacing `print ("Target image loaded" + target_image)` with `print ("Target image loaded" + str(target_image))` but when we run it again, the script starts loading the target image and then halts a few lines later after printing out arrays of numbers like this:

```
[ INFO:0] Initialize OpenCL runtime...
Using OpenCL: True.
Output directory: /Users/example/Development/deep/pic/pic_output.
Scanned videos will be moved to: /Users/example/Development/deep/pic/pic_scanned_vids.
Target image loaded[[[199 196 191]
  [199 196 191]
  [199 196 191]
  ...
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]]

 [[199 196 191]
  [199 196 191]
  [199 196 191]
  ...
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]]

 [[199 196 191]
  [199 196 191]
  [200 197 192]
  ...
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]
  [184 180 177]]

 ...

 [[166 166 166]
  [164 164 164]
  [165 165 167]
  ...
  [148 149 151]
  [146 148 145]
  [146 147 142]]

 [[166 166 166]
  [164 164 164]
  [165 165 167]
  ...
  [149 150 152]
  [146 148 145]
  [146 147 142]]

 [[166 166 166]
  [164 164 164]
  [165 165 167]
  ...
  [150 151 153]
  [146 148 145]
  [146 147 142]]]
```

I've tried it on a few different versions of python, but nothing seems to change.

Here's the script:

```
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import random
import string
import os
import math
import argparse


os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser();
parser.add_argument('-i', type=str, help='Image of target face to scan for.', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-v', type=str, help='Video to process', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-t', type=float, help='Tolerance of face detection, lower is stricter. (0.1-1.0)', default=0.6)
parser.add_argument('-f', type=int, help='Amount of frames per second to extract.', default=25)
parser.add_argument('-n', type=int, help='Number of frames with target face to save from each vid.', default=1000)
parser.add_argument('-s', type=int, help='Minimum KB size of images to keep in the faceset.', default=32)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

if args['t'] > 1.0:
    args['t'] = 1.0
elif args['t'] < 0.1:
    args['t'] = 0.1

min_KB = args['s']
tol = args['t']
xfps = args['f']
targfname = args['i']
vid_dir = args['v']
faces_from_each_video = args['n']

if faces_from_each_video < 1:
    faces_from_each_video = 1000

if min_KB < 1:
    min_KB = 32

print("Target filename: " + targfname + ".")
print("Video input directory: " + vid_dir + ".")
print("Tolerance: " + str(tol) + ".")
print("Number of confirmed faces saved from each video: " + str(faces_from_each_video) + ".")

if(cv2.ocl.haveOpenCL()):
    cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(True)
    print("Using OpenCL: " + str(cv2.ocl.useOpenCL()) + ".")

target_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(targfname)
outdir = str(str(os.path.splitext(targfname)[0]) + "_output");
scanned_vids = str(str(os.path.splitext(targfname)[0]) + "_scanned_vids");
too_small = str(str(os.path.splitext(targfname)[0]) + "_too_small");

#check if output directories already exists, and if not, create it
os.makedirs(outdir, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(scanned_vids, exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs(too_small, exist_ok=True)

print("Output directory: " + outdir + ".")
print("Scanned videos will be moved to: " + scanned_vids + ".")

try:
    print ("Target image loaded" + str(target_image))
    target_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(target_image)[0]
except IndexError:
    print("No face found in target image.")
    raise SystemExit(0)
vid = True
while(vid):
    try:
        vid = random.choice(glob.glob(vid_dir + '*.mp4'))
        print("Now looking at video: " + vid)
        input_video = cv2.VideoCapture(vid)

        framenum = 0
        vidheight = input_video.get(4)
        vidwidth = input_video.get(3)
        vidfps = input_video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        totalframes = input_video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
        outputsize = 256, 256

        if xfps > vidfps:
            xfps = vidfps

        print("Frame Width: " + str(vidwidth) + ", Height: " + str(vidheight) + ".")

        known_faces = [
            target_encoding
        ]

        def random_string(length):
            return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for m in range(length))

        #switch to output directory
        os.chdir(str(os.path.splitext(targfname)[0]) + "_output")

        written = 1
        while(input_video.isOpened()):
            input_video.set(1, (framenum + (vidfps/xfps)))
            framenum += vidfps/xfps
            ret, frame = input_video.read()

            if not ret:
                break

            percentage = (framenum/totalframes)*100
            print("Checking frame " + str(int(framenum)) + "/" + str(int(totalframes)) + str(" (%.2f%%)" % percentage))

            rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

            face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
            face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

            for fenc, floc in zip(face_encodings, face_locations):
                istarget = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_faces, fenc, tolerance=float(tol))

                #if the face found matches the target
                if istarget[0]:
                    top, right, bottom, left = floc
                    facefound = True
                    #squaring it up
                    if (bottom - top) > (right - left):
                        right = left + (bottom - top)
                    elif (right - left) > (bottom - top):
                        bottom = top + (right - left)
                    #calculating the diagonal of the cropped face for rotation purposes
                    #diagonal = math.sqrt(2*(bottom - top))
                    #padding = diagonal / 2
                    #alignment script causes images cropped "too closely" to get a bit fucky, so crop them less severely.
                    padding = (bottom - top)/2

                    if((top - padding >= 0) and (bottom + padding <= vidheight) and (left - padding >= 0) and (right + padding <= vidwidth)):
                        croppedframe = frame[int(top - padding):int(bottom + padding), int(left - padding):int(right + padding)]
                        #if the image is too small, resize it to outputsize
                        cheight, cwidth, cchannels = croppedframe.shape
                        if (cheight < 256) or (cwidth < 256):
                            croppedframe = cv2.resize(croppedframe, outputsize, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                        print('Writing image ' + str(written) + '.')
                        cv2.imwrite(("vid_" + str(zz) + random_string(15) + ".jpg"), croppedframe, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 98])
                        written += 1
            if percentage > 99.9:
                os.rename(vid, scanned_vids + '/vid' + str(zz) + '_' + random_string(5) + '.mp4')
                break
            if written > faces_from_each_video:
                os.rename(vid, scanned_vids + '/vid' + str(zz) + '_' + random_string(5) + '.mp4')
                break
        input_video.release()
    except ValueError:
        print ("Scanning videos complete.")
        pass
    except IndexError:
        pass
#Removes images under 32KB
counter = 0
low_quat = min_KB * 1000
for xx in (os.listdir(os.getcwd())):
    if(os.path.getsize(xx)) < low_quat:
        os.rename(xx, too_small + "/too small-" + str(counter) + random_string(15) + ".jpg")
        print ("Moving " + str(xx) + " to the too small folder")
        counter += 1


#Remove images with more than one face
print ("Now double checking there is only one face in each photo")
for yy in (os.listdir(os.getcwd())):
    # Load the jpg file into a numpy array
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(yy)

    # Find all the faces in the image using a pre-trained convolutional neural network.
    # This method is more accurate than the default HOG model, but it's slower
    # unless you have an nvidia GPU and dlib compiled with CUDA extensions. But if you do,
    # this will use GPU acceleration and perform well.
    # See also: find_faces_in_picture.py
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image, number_of_times_to_upsample=0, model="cnn")

    print("I found {} face(s) in this photograph.".format(len(face_locations)))

    if not (len(face_locations)) == 1:
        os.remove(yy)
        print (str(yy) + ' was removed')
```

I don't even know where to begin trying to solve this, so any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you define `random_string(length)` in the while loop???? Take it outside of the loop. As a side note, your `try/except` block is way too broad.

Comment: Download Pycharm or another IDE, and start debugging, line by line.

Answer (score 1):

We can see that `print ("Target image loaded" + str(target_image))` is being executed because `Target image loaded` is printed, and if that is printed, so is `str(target_image)`, so what follows must be just that.  `[[[199 196 191] ... looks like a 2-D array of RGB triples.

Perhaps the program is meant to print the name of the target image, not its contents.